# Camera zoom com touch na Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou trabalhando com este código abaixo controlar a distância da câmera até o personagem, esta distância é o resultado da interpolação linear entre um offset mínimo e máximo, onde a variável `float distance` controla este resultado.

```
Vector3.Lerp(minOffset, maxOffset, distance)
```

Porém na função de zoom o resultado do `Vector2.Distance` está sendo bastante grande, entre 110.000 e 890.000, o que com certeza foge do mínimo e máximo necessário para controlar o Lerp.

```
void Zoom()
{
    if (Input.touchCount != 2)
        return;

    Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);
    Touch touch1 = Input.GetTouch(1);

    if(touch0.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        distance = Vector2.Distance(touch0.position, touch1.position);
    }
}
```

Já tentei utilizando `Mathf.Clamp`, mas logicamente o valor do `Vector2.Distance` é bastante grande para que o resultado seja menor que 1F.

```
distance = Mathf.Clamp(Vector2.Distance(touch0.position, touch1.position), 0F, 1F)
```

Como eu posso reduzir o mínimo e o máximo do `Vector2.Distance` à min 0F e max 1F?

Lembrando que devo considerar que em alguns dispositivos o resultado entre o `touch0` e `touch1` no `Vector2.Distance` pode ser maior.

Comment: Tem um script que faz algo similar a isso no Asset Store:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14489
Com um pouco de alteração no código, pode ser fácil chegar à solução.

Answer (score 0):

Estou sem a Unity3D instalada no momento para testar, mas eu tenho a impressão de que o [`Touch.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) retorna um `Vector2` com a coordenada **na tela**. Assim, o cálculo da distância vai retornar uma medida em pixels, de forma que quanto maior a resolução da imagem apresentada, maior será o número devolvido para mesmas posições dos dedos.

Dessa forma, o que você pode tentar fazer é calcular a distância entre os vetores das posições normalizados, usando o atributo [`normalized`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-normalized.html):

```
distance = Vector2.Distance(touch0.position.normalized, touch1.position.normalized);
```

Um vetor normalizado tem as coordenadas ajustadas de forma que sua magnitude se torne 1. Assim, o seu cálculo de distância entre as coordenadas normalizadas fica independente da resolução da tela utilizada. Note que essa distância vai ser pequena e com variações decimais. Use-a para ponderar a distância da câmera de forma similar à que você já está fazendo.